# std::memcpy and copying data from 2D vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, memcpy

I have `int *a` with for 5x4 matrix, where 5 is row and 4 is column.

The memory allocation for a matrix is column are continuous and every row is started after individual column.

I like to copy data from `vector< vector <int>> b;`

`b` also have same size and dimension have 5 rows and 4 columns.

How I obtained data for `b` is

```
b.resize(5);
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    b[i].resize(4);
}
```

I like to copy data from `b` to `a`.
Is it possible to use `std::memcpy(a, &b, sizeof (int)*20)`?

EDIT:

Sorry I like to copy the other way.
`std::memcpy(&b, a, sizeof (int)*20)`

Comment: @VTT Sorry I like to copy the other way. I edited.

Comment: It does not matter in which direction you want to copy, you just need to copy from / to buffer of vector, that is using pointer returned by `vector::data()` method. Also since `b` is contains vectors you will need to iterate over those vectors as well.

Comment: A `vector<vector<T>>` is closer to an array of pointers than to a 2D array. Rows are not contiguous so you cannot use a single memcopy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use a single `std::memcpy` to go from a flattened matrix (`int[]`) to a proper matrix (`std::vector<std::vector<int>>`). For two reasons. First, there is no way to tell `std::memcpy` the matrix dimensions. Second, the 'rows' in the `std::vector` matrix are not required to be sequential in memory, but `std::memcpy` only copies to a single address.

Comment: y that is I like to confirm. you did the point (std::vector matrix are not required to be sequential in memory).

Answer (score 1):

`b` has a a contiguous buffer in memory, accessible via its `data()` method. Each element of this buffer is another `std::vector`, which in turn has its own buffer pointing somewhere else. This means that you can't use a single call to `memcpy` to copy to all these 2nd level buffers.

Comment: y I can use memcpy only for column vectors, not for rows.